# Does the notification order of TaskExecutionListeners match the order of registration in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Will the following always print `one, two, three` in order if I run `gradle three`?

```groovy
task one {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask(it)) {
            println "one"
        }
    }
}

task two {
    dependsOn one
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask(it)) {
            println "two"
        }
    }
}

task three {
    dependsOn two
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask(it)) {
            println "three"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes as the closures get put into a `LinkedHashMap`, ultimately it goes into a [BroadcastDispatch](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/379def16e573f7a73a9b5ace9e5c2c69dbb2d0f2/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/listener/BroadcastDispatch.java) when you call `whenReady`

there is nothing in the public api that states this though